# How to disable front page view programmatically?

Tags: views, 8

I have another view that uses the same path as the front page view which is "/node" and I will like to disable the front page view programmatically.

How can I do that from a **hook_install**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Views are entities, so:

1. Load the View:

   ```
   $view_id = 'content'; // Replace with the ID of the view you wish to disable.
   $view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('view')->load($view_id);
   ```
2. Update the status:

   ```
   $view->setStatus(FALSE);
   ```
3. And save it:

   ```
   $view->save();
   ```

Or all in one go:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('view')
  ->load($view_id)
  ->setStatus(FALSE)
  ->save();
```

Comment: Perfect.  It looks as if the preferred invocation is now entityTypeManager as per https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler - with the only real drawbacks being that you need a use statement for `View` and it assumes that is the class for view objects, which would be very unusual not to be the case:

```
View::load('content')->disable()->save();
```