# How do I stop a module from installing optional configuration, or make sure it's installed by the time I want to remove it myself?

Tags: 8, installation, configuration

I don't want the "Frontpage" view to be installed along with my installation profile.

I tried adding a `hook_install` to a module which does this:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('view')
  ->load('frontpage')
  ->setStatus(FALSE)
  ->save();
```

But during installation that tells me that the frontpage view doesn't exist when my module is being installed. Fair enough, so I added the module that owns the frontpage view config (core node) to my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  - drupal:node
```

Still didn't work. Then I realised it's optional config; maybe the module responsible for processing that config (core views) also needs to be a dependency. It would make sense, so my dependencies became:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  - drupal:node
  - drupal:views
```

Still didn't work, same problem - the View simply doesn't exist yet, so it can't be deleted.

So two halves of the same question:

1. How do I stop this config from ever having been installed in the first place (or installed but initially disabled)?
2. If that's not possible, what dependencies do I need to provide to ensure that the View in question is installed by the time my own `hook_install` is executed, so I can remove/disable it myself?

Comment: `But during installation that tells me that the frontpage view doesn't exist` did you try installing your module in a fresh/vanilla Drupal install? I only ask since [your answer worked for Darol](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187473/how-to-disable-front-page-view-programmatically). So either something changed since '16 or something is going on with your Drupal.

Comment: @NoSssweat I did - the content View isn’t optional conf, I wonder if that’s the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, have you tried in the .profile file an [hook_install_tasks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/8.5.x)?

Or maybe with the hook_install_tasks_alter.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install_tasks_alter().
 */
function MODULE_install_tasks_alter(array &$tasks, array $install_state) {
  $tasks['install_finished']['function'] = 'CALLBACK_post_install';
}
```

And deactivate the view in the callback.

Comment: Turns out `hook_install` is the best place to do this, but moving it to the install profile was definitely the way to go. Thanks